# Can I submit a form with only hidden fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, post

I'm loading different forms into the same div, based on a drop down... all the others seem to work when they're told to submit via JQuery except this one... anyone know why? Thanks....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInMemoryPayment", "Payment", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<p> Payment type: Cash. No further action needed. Plase click Save to finish. </p>


<input type="hidden" name="PaymentTypeID" id="paymentTypeIDHidden" value="@Model.PaymentTypeID" />
<input type="hidden" name="DonationID" id="donationIDHidden" value="@Model.DonationID" />
<input type="hidden" name="PaymentDate" id="paymentDateHidden" value="@Model.PaymentDate" />
<input type="hidden" name="PaymentAmount" id="paymentAmountHidden" value="@Model.PaymentAmount" /> 

}
```

Here's a form that does work...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInMemoryPayment", "Payment", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<p>Check information:</p>

<div class="editor-label" id="check1">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CheckNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="check1.2">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CheckNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckNumber)
    </div>


@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentTypeID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DonationID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentAmount)


}
```

They both post back to the same place... but the first one won't. These forms are loaded into a div in a parent view that has a save button... that button opens a dialog, that has an OK button with this in its click: $('#paymentSection2').find('form').submit();

Comment: Why aren't you using `@Html.HiddenFor()`?

Comment: @Brad: Why would that matter?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? To answer your question, Yes, you can have a form containing only hidden fields.

Comment: @scottm I added a little more detail to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can submit a form with only hidden fields.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using [`@Html.HiddenFor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor.aspx)? Chances are it's a binding issue and MVC can't distinguish your input names and the input names its expecting. (e.g. It may be expecting `MyModel.PaymentID` instead of just `PaymentID` as an input name).

Try the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInMemoryPayment", "Payment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <p> Payment type: Cash. No further action needed. Plase click Save to finish. </p>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentTypeID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DonationID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentAmount)
}
```